# Making mouse cursor/pointer of ArcMap HTML Popup tool larger?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, accessibility, mouse-cursor

Next week I'm giving a presentation, using the ArcMap application of ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop , where to make things easier for the audience to see what I am doing, I would like to increase the mouse pointer size, in this case for the HTML Popup tool.

I have already gone to ArcMap's `Customize | Customize Mode` and its `Options` tab to make sure that `Large Icons` is checked on, but this seems to only affect icon sizes on toolbars.

I've also gone to Windows 7's `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Center\Make the mouse easier to use` to make sure that I am using `Extra Large Inverting`.

Is there somewhere else that I can go to make the HTML Popup tool (or all tools) use a mouse pointer icon that is about twice as high and wide as it is now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you'll be able to change the settings of the mouse pointer for just the HTML Popup tool.  But you can certainly change the size and style of the mouse pointer in Windows Control Panel.

Go to the Mouse settings and select the Pointers Tab. There are several options there that might be suitable.  I chose Windows Standard (extra large)(system scheme) which is the same as what you have already done.

[image]

However, there are several cursors which you can download which might be more suitable. A Google Search will yield a lot of results.

Alternatively, in the Pointer Options tab, you can improve visibility by turning on **Display pointer trails** and possibly even **Show location of pointer when I press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key**. I find this last option is actually pretty effective, especially if you press it a couple times.

[image]

Comment: This has certainly been helpful.  I had most of those settings except for pointer trails which I have now turned on to good effect.  In your first screenshot under Customize, are you saying that if I download a replacement for the Link Select item that it will show up on the HTML Popup tool?  If so, any more advice you can give on where to find a suitable download and how to do that will be appreciated.

Comment: To be honest, I've never customised my pointers. But I searched online and a lot of sites came up. I'm not sure what the behaviour will be for link select if you assign a new icon for that pointer type.

Comment: No problem I think you must have seen sites like http://www.digitalcitizen.life/top-10-best-mouse-cursor-schemes-windows but I think bringing one of them in is overkill for what I need so I think I'll just work with pointer trails for a bit to see if they'll help meet my objective which is just to let the audience see where I'm pointing with the HTML Popup tool a little easier.